# How to Tar all directories somewhere, separately, and put them elsewhere

Tags: bash, tar

I'd like, with a small script, to be able to tar all directories that are inside: `/One`

but have  all the created tar.gz files saved into another directory: `/Two`

And each Tar'd directory would be a different tar.gz file, rather than all together.

I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and globbing (`*`):

```
cd /One && for dir in *; do tar -cvf "/Two/${dir}.tar" "$dir";  done
```

I assume that the directory `/One` in the first level contains only directories.